# Android export process keeps failing

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm having an issue suddenly with the export process in Eclipse for licensing my Android app prior to release.

When I build normally under debug mode and deploy to the device, the file size is 11,782Mb. When I use the export process, the file is smaller, 11,322Mb. The file is corrupt and won't load when I test it on the device. When this process is successful, the file is the same size.

This happened once or twice before, and usually cleaning and rebuilding the project sorted it out, but now it's happening every time no matter what I do. Any ideas what is happening here please?

Edit: Production key is fine, use it all the time.

When I attempt to install the app, I get ClassNotFoundException:
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.myapp.android.App: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.myapp.android.App" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp.app-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.myapp.app-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Comment: "corrupt and won't load" - do you have a logcat? console output? what is the error?

Comment: As you have not provided much information just a wild guess: has your production key expired?

Comment: Original question edited to answer your comments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possible reasons for `ClassNotFoundException` that I have run into. Here are a few suggestions:

1. You mentioned "clean and rebuild" - for some reason (usually related to compiling the `R.java` file) I occasionally need to "clean" more than once for a good production build. I can even do a "clean" and export on a test that is fine, then do an export with a fail. I've probably done over 1000 deployments to Google Play across 50+ apps. It happens...
2. Android's Installer is corrupt. Yes - this happens, too. Sometimes with a production deployment (not with "debug" or "AVD" - but with "ADB" install or production installs) the Android installer will not *ever* install your app again. Factory reset of the device is the only solution. I believe an Android OS update can solve the problem, but I've only seen that work intermittently and haven't really tested it.
3. Manifest errors. Sometimes the production manifest file doesn't match the app classes. Usually this happens with a refactoring of class names. Eclipse in particular does not seem to always modify the manifest file properly. You may need to check it manually.
4. A `res` file changed. Sometimes when editing an XML document you will have an error that is not picked up by the compiler or IDE. You do a build and deploy to a test device that for some reason doesn't seem to use the resource or some other strange error. Usually it won't deploy anywhere properly, but I've seen it deploy to a test device and then not deploy in production. As a practice, I avoid this problem by occasionally "uninstalling" and then re-installing the app during testing.
5. The OP reminded me of another along the lines of the comment below (for future readers) - try deleting the generated files from the build. For example, anything in "BIN" and "GEN" can be deleted and re-built using "build." These files sometimes contain artifacts from previous builds that are no longer valid but are not detected during an automatic build process.

Those are some suggestions. Give them a try...

Comment: It's an odd one, took me ages to get this to work. Ultimately I had to manually delete all files from the bin folder as well as continuous refreshing and cleaning the project. Thanks for taking the time to answer, which I'll accept.

Comment: Thanks! And I added a comment about "BIN" and other automatically generated folders/files. I've had that problem, too...